# Maven plugin in child inherited from parent ignores configuration block in child

Tags: java, maven

I maintain a large number of child Maven poms that inherit from a parent pom, but presently only define dependencies to inherit.  I'm now working on implementing plugin inheritance.  In one of my services, I'm just stepping through the plugins, copying the block to my parent pom and just having the child just specify the `groupId` and `artifactId`.  In the effective pom, it correctly gets the inherited plugin version.  Up to now, all the required configuration has been defined in the parent.  I'm now working on one where the child defines a `configuration` block.  In this case the parent doesn't even define a `configuration` block, but it does define several `executions`, which appear to be inherited correctly.

What I see in the effective pom is that the `configuration` block is always taken from the parent pom.  The child pom `configuration` block is ignored.  Initially, the parent pom had an empty `configuration` block, and the resulting block in the child was also empty, ignoring what was in the child pom.  I then added some dummy configuration to the parent, and that was echoed in the child, again ignoring the child pom.

I thought the default was "child overrides", but it doesn't seem to be working that way.

I tried temporarily removing the plugin definition from the parent, and that fixes the child, using the configuration block in the child pom.

I'm using Maven 3.8.2.  The plugin I'm working on right now is `jacoco-maven-plugin`, but I imagine that's irrelevant.

This is the `plugin` block from the parent (inside `pluginManagement`):

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
    <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${jacoco.maven.plugin.version}</version>
    <configuration>
        <excludes> <exclude>abc</exclude> </excludes>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>pre-unit-test</id>
            <goals> <goal>prepare-agent</goal> </goals>
            <configuration>
                <propertyName>surefireArgLine</propertyName>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>post-unit-test</id>
            <phase>test</phase>
            <goals> <goal>report</goal> </goals>
            <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>${jacoco.path}</outputDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>pre-integration-test</id>
            <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
            <goals> <goal>prepare-agent</goal> </goals>
            <configuration>
                <destFile>${sonar.jacoco.itReportPath}</destFile>
                <propertyName>failsafeArgLine</propertyName>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>post-integration-test</id>
            <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
            <goals> <goal>report</goal> </goals>
            <configuration>
                <dataFile>${sonar.jacoco.itReportPath}/</dataFile>
                <outputDirectory>${jacoco.itPath}</outputDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

This is what is in the child pom.xml:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
    <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <excludes>
            <exclude>{specificpath}</exclude>
            ...
        </excludes>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Note that "{specificpath}" is just a placeholder. It has a valid path in the pom.xml.

This is what the effective pom ends up as (again, somewhat elided):

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
  <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>0.8.5</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>pre-unit-test</id>
      <goals>
        <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <propertyName>surefireArgLine</propertyName>
        <excludes>
          <exclude>abc</exclude>
        </excludes>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
    <execution>
      <id>post-unit-test</id>
      <phase>test</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>report</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <outputDirectory>.../target/jacoco_report</outputDirectory>
        <excludes>
          <exclude>abc</exclude>
        </excludes>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
    <execution>
      <id>pre-integration-test</id>
      <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <destFile>${sonar.jacoco.itReportPath}</destFile>
        <propertyName>failsafeArgLine</propertyName>
        <excludes>
          <exclude>abc</exclude>
        </excludes>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
    <execution>
      <id>post-integration-test</id>
      <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>report</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <dataFile>${sonar.jacoco.itReportPath}/</dataFile>
        <outputDirectory>.../target/jacoco_itReport</outputDirectory>
        <excludes>
          <exclude>abc</exclude>
        </excludes>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
  <configuration>
    <excludes>
      <exclude>abc</exclude>
    </excludes>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

You'll notice that the overall configuration just has the `abc` exclude from the parent, not the `{specificpath}` from the child.  That `abc` exclusion is also pushed into the `configuration` blocks in each of the `execution` blocks.

It seems likely to me that this problem has something to do with the fact that I have `configuration` blocks in each `execution` block, but I don't know what to do about that.

If I temporarily remove the `plugin` definition in the parent, and restore it all to the child pom, this is what I get in the effective pom:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
  <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>0.8.8</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>pre-unit-test</id>
      <goals>
        <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <propertyName>surefireArgLine</propertyName>
        <excludes>
          <exclude>{specificpath}</exclude>
          ...
        </excludes>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
    <execution>
      <id>post-unit-test</id>
      <phase>test</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>report</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <outputDirectory>.../target/jacoco_report</outputDirectory>
        <excludes>
          <exclude>{specificpath}</exclude>
          ...
        </excludes>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
    <execution>
      <id>pre-integration-test</id>
      <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <destFile>${sonar.jacoco.itReportPath}</destFile>
        <propertyName>failsafeArgLine</propertyName>
        <excludes>
          <exclude>{specificpath}</exclude>
          ...
        </excludes>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
    <execution>
      <id>post-integration-test</id>
      <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>report</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <dataFile>${sonar.jacoco.itReportPath}/</dataFile>
        <outputDirectory>.../target/jacoco_itReport</outputDirectory>
        <excludes>
          <exclude>{specificpath}</exclude>
          ...
        </excludes>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
  <configuration>
    <excludes>
          <exclude>{specificpath}</exclude>
          ...
    </excludes>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Best is to make a full working example on github or alike...

Comment: Hmph. I'm perplexed by the result from this. It's not so much the example that is perplexing. I put that together quickly, but it doesn't demonstrate the problem. What is perplexing is that I went back to my original project and generated the effective pom again, and now this is not happening. It's using the child configuration as expected. Curiously, the "Effective POM" display in Eclipse actually took several seconds to display this time, whereas yesterday it was appearing immediately. Hopefully I won't have odd things like this happen again.

Comment: Ah, I see where I got confused.  The plugin definition appears twice, one in pluginManagement, and once in plugins. When I searched from the top, I found the one in pluginManagement.  The first one is just a copy of the same plugin from the parent, but the second one, in plugins, is where merging takes place. The second one looks as I expect.

Comment: My impression on such a configuration is there is fundamentally something wrong because you are targeting the output into a different module via `<outputDirectory>../target..</outputDirectory>` better would be to merge goal and maybe a separate module for things like that... If you can make an example project on Github I could take a deeper look and make PR's help here...

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that. Those "outputDirectory" values are all elided. They all begin with "${project.build.directory}". They don't go to different modules.  I already determined that there was no error here. My "Ah" comment states this. I should delete the question, but I imagine other people might make the same mistake at some point.

Comment: Can you please make a full example on github oralike ... we can take a deepeer look...

Answer (score 0):

I cannot say what went wrong in configuration hell.

What I can say is that you are usually better off by defining the configuration in the parent using properties (like `${some.prop}`) and then overriding the properties in the child (`<properties><some.prop>C:\mydir</some.prop></properties>`).